# How to locate unposted Google Docs comments

Tags: comments, google-docs

The typical process to add a comment to a Google Doc is to...

1. Highlight some part of the document
2. Click the icon to add the document
3. Type the text of the comment
4. Click the "Comment" button on the comment bubble to "Post" the comment.
   The problem I experience is that I sometimes forget step #4, to click the "Comment" button to post the comment before I move on to other parts of the document.

This means that the comment is not saved and will be lost if the document is closed.

When you do this, and you try to close the document, you get the warning "Changes you made may not be saved" and if you continue to close the document, your unposted comments are lost.

So how do you quickly find the unposted comment in a large document?  I have found the only solution to be to scroll through all pages of the document looking for the unposted comment.  This can be tedious for a very long and highly commented document.

Solutions that post all unposted comments would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use comments a lot, but Google's got all the corners covered: up on the top right, there's a button directly on the left of the Share button with a little speech bubble:
[Google Docs comment button highlighted yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRMr6.png)
There you'll be able to find all of the comments.
If that doesn't work, then the unposted comment is unfortunately truly lost and the only way to get it back is to retype it.
You'll be happy to know, however, that there is a keyboard shortcut to comment: `ctrl+enter`. Simple, in theory.
Hope this helps!

Comment: beackers, your suggested solution is how to show all comments.  But, the issue I am describing is say, there are 100 comments in a 50 page document, so how do I find the unposted one without scrolling through all the pages and comments.  This is the real issue.

Comment: As of right now there is no "search" implemented in the comments section. But what you might be able to do is use the browser Find function (Ctrl-F on linux and windows or Command-F on mac).
Most likely Google Docs will not save an unposted comment (it being unposted).